# are 2^n exponent calculations really less efficient than bit-shifts?

Tags: objective-c, c

if I do:

```
int x = 4;
pow(2, x);
```

Is that really that much less efficient than just doing:

```
1 << 4
```

?

Comment: How much is "that much"? You must expect it to be less efficient, else you wouldn't ask the question. So what we have here is a frivolous question with no attempt at research that expects mindreading. -1

Comment: It wasn't that I was expecting it, someone had commented on a pow(2, x); I had in my code and said "always do bit shifting instead of powers of 2", and I had never heard that before, so that is why I asked the question here.

Comment: It seems the second method (1<<4 ) is limited to 32 , assuming 4 byte integers. In other words maximum you can calculate is (1<<32) . an any one suggest a trick to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes. An easy way to show this is to compile the following two functions that do the same thing and then look at the disassembly.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

uint32_t foo1(uint32_t shftAmt) {
    return pow(2, shftAmt);
}

uint32_t foo2(uint32_t shftAmt) {
    return (1 << shftAmt);
}
```

`cc -arch armv7 -O3 -S -o - shift.c` (I happen to find ARM asm easier to read but if you want x86 just remove the arch flag)

```
    _foo1:
@ BB#0:
    push    {r7, lr}
    vmov    s0, r0
    mov r7, sp
    vcvt.f64.u32    d16, s0
    vmov    r0, r1, d16
    blx _exp2
    vmov    d16, r0, r1
    vcvt.u32.f64    s0, d16
    vmov    r0, s0
    pop {r7, pc}

_foo2:
@ BB#0:
    movs    r1, #1
    lsl.w   r0, r1, r0
    bx  lr
```

You can see `foo2` only takes 2 instructions vs `foo1` which takes several instructions. It has to move the data to the FP HW registers (`vmov`), convert the integer to a float (`vcvt.f64.u32`) call the `exp` function and then convert the answer back to an uint (`vcvt.u32.f64`) and move it from the FP HW back to the GP registers.

Comment: Most of the time will be taken in the _exp2 function, not in any of the code shown here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Though by how much I can't say.  The easiest way to determine that is to benchmark it.

The `pow` function uses doubles...  At least, if it conforms to the C standard.  Even if that function used bitshift when it sees a base of `2`, there would still be testing and branching to reach that conclusion, by which time your simple bitshift would be completed.  And we haven't even considered the overhead of a function call yet.

For equivalency, I assume you meant to use `1 << x` instead of `1 << 4`.

Perhaps a compiler could optimize both of these, but it's far less likely to optimize a call to `pow`.  If you need the fastest way to compute a power of 2, do it with shifting.

Update...  Since I mentioned it's easy to benchmark, I decided to do just that.  I happen to have Windows and Visual C++ handy so I used that.  Results will vary.  My program:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

LARGE_INTEGER liFreq, liStart, liStop;


inline void StartTimer()
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStart);
}


inline double ReportTimer()
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStop);
    double milli = 1000.0 * double(liStop.QuadPart - liStart.QuadPart) / double(liFreq.QuadPart);
    printf( "%.3f ms\n", milli );
    return milli;
}


int main()
{    
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liFreq);

    const size_t nTests = 10000000;
    int x = 4;
    int sumPow = 0;
    int sumShift = 0;

    double powTime, shiftTime;

    // Make an array of random exponents to use in tests.
    const size_t nExp = 10000;
    int e[nExp];
    srand( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );
    for( int i = 0; i < nExp; i++ ) e[i] = rand() % 31;

    // Test power.
    StartTimer();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nTests; i++ )
    {
        int y = (int)pow(2, (double)e[i%nExp]);
        sumPow += y;
    }
    powTime = ReportTimer();

    // Test shifting.
    StartTimer();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nTests; i++ )
    {
        int y = 1 << e[i%nExp];
        sumShift += y;
    }
    shiftTime = ReportTimer();

    // The compiler shouldn't optimize out our loops if we need to display a result.
    printf( "Sum power: %d\n", sumPow );
    printf( "Sum shift: %d\n", sumShift );

    printf( "Time ratio of pow versus shift: %.2f\n", powTime / shiftTime );

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
379.466 ms
15.862 ms
Sum power: 157650768
Sum shift: 157650768
Time ratio of pow versus shift: 23.92
```

Comment: You can't just shift a floating point number to exponentiate it even if the base is `2`.

Comment: @CarlNorum I know, but you could test that it is in integer range and use integers.  That was my point...  But such testing would make it even slower.

Comment: I added benchmarking code and results from a Windows platform using Visual C++ (since that's what I happen to be using).

Comment: This answer (among others) strikes me as massive overkill while missing a fundamental point: If math.h is included, the OP's example can be computed at compile time (because pow is a standard function). But if it cannot be computed at compile time, then the pow call will of course be significantly slower than the shift (in any implementation not designed specifically to make that statement false).

Comment: Well, to be sure there was no code example until natural curiosity led me to do it... =)  But I think it's a bit rough to be arguing this from the viewpoint that the OP's code can be optimized easily into a constant value.  Reading between the lines, don't you think they were asking about efficiency because they want to do something a little more intensive than that?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the compiler, but in general (when the compiler is not totally braindead) yes, the shift is one CPU instruction, the other is a function call, that involves saving the current state an setting up a stack frame, that requires many instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, as bit shift is very basic operation for the processor.

On the other hand many compilers optimise code so that raising to power is in fact just a bit shifting.

Comment: Not if you're calling `pow()`, which is the OP's example.

Comment: @CarlNorum In the OP's example, both the exponent and the power are `int`s; if math.h is included, the compiler is free to optimize it using `int` operations. In fact, since the operands are both known at compile time, it is free to replace it with a constant. Actually, since the result isn't used, it's free to emit no code at all.