# C++ program for power but without using pow function

Tags: c++

I'm a newbee in C++ and I'm writing a C++ program that asks the user to input two integers and then it raises the first integer to the power specified by the second integer. For example, if the user enters 5 and 8, the result will be 5 subscript 8, i.e., number five will be raised to the eighth power. The program must not use **any pre-defined C++ functions (like pow function)** for this task. The program should allow the user to perform another calculation if they so desire. Can anyone help

Comment: What have you tried ? Perhaps you could create a loop that multiplies 5 with itself 8 times.

Comment: Oh my, you will have to drop down to assembler and handle everything there if you cannot use predefined c++ functions!

Comment: does `main` count as a "predefined function"?

Comment: darn it (comment too short)

Comment: @user3371651: *Really*? If that is the case, the question is more suited for a `embedded` than `c++` tag. It's hard to believe that you need to avoid `main`, so my first recommendation is to go back and understand what you are asked to do.

Comment: What about multiple multiplication operations in a loop?!!? That's some **very basic** algo!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The program must not use any pre-defined C++ functions (like pow function) for this task

You can use some piece of c++ code like follows, to compute **x<sup>y</sup>**, without using any predefined function:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;
int result = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
{
    result *= x;
}

cout << result << endl;
```

Output:

```
125
```

See a working sample [here](http://ideone.com/BQpmiJ).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to give you any code, because that won't allow you to truly explore this concept. Rather, you should use this pseudo code to implement something on your own.

Create a function which accepts two inputs, the base and the exponent.

Now there are several ways to go about doing this. You can use efficient bit shifting, but let's start simple, shall we?

```
answer = base
i = 1
while i is less than or equal to exponent
    answer = answer * base
return answer
```

Simply loop through multiplying the base by itself.

There are other ways that focus on efficiency. Look here to see something that you may want to attempt: [are 2^n exponent calculations really less efficient than bit-shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556906/are-2n-exponent-calculations-really-less-efficient-than-bit-shifts)