# Function gets right pointer but returns NULL

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm creating a binary tree in C in which I use indexes as in a binary search tree. I'm having trouble with a function that finds a node.

My code for the tree is in a separate file and it's the following:

```
struct node {
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  int index;
  void *data;
};

struct node * init_mt()
{
  struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  root->index = -1;
  root->data = NULL;
  root->left = root->right = NULL;
  return root;
}

void create_mt(struct node *mt, int h, int i)
{
  if (h == 0) // end of tree reached
  {
    mt->index = 0;
    mt->left = mt->right = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else 
  {
    mt->index = i;
    int l = i-pow(2,h-1);
    int r = i+pow(2,h-1);
    mt->left = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    mt->right = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    create_mt(mt->left,h-1,l);
    create_mt(mt->right,h-1,r);
  }
}

struct node * get_node_mt(struct node *mt, int p, int h)
{
  if (h == -1) // end of tree reached
  { 
    return NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    if (mt->index == p)
    {
      printf("Found %p\n", mt);
      return mt;
    }
    else if (mt->index > p)
    {
      get_node_mt(mt->left,p,h-1);
    }
    else
    {
      get_node_mt(mt->right,p,h-1);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my main like this (root->left->left is the node index #2):

```
struct node *root = NULL;
root = init_mt();
create_mt(root,3,8); // root index == 8
printf("%d %p\n", root->left->left->index,root->left->left);
struct node *find;
find = get_node_mt(root,2,3);
printf("%p\n", find);
```

I get the following output:

```
2 0x7ffd1dd011a0
Found 0x7ffd1dd011a0
0x0
```

I don't understand why I get the right pointer both when priting directly using root->left->left and inside the function get_node_mt() but not when I print the pointer I've returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Using FP math in `int l = i-pow(2,h-1);` is weak programming. Recommend calculating power-of-2 with integer math.

Comment: @chux what do you mean? And how do I do that? Is it a cast (int) ok?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556906/are-2n-exponent-calculations-really-less-efficient-than-bit-shifts and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get_node_mt() function calls itself in two places. Neither of these two places return a value.

```
struct node * get_node_mt(struct node *mt, int p, int h)
{
    if (h == -1) // end of tree reached
        return NULL;
    else if (mt->index == p)
        return mt;
    else if (mt->index > p)
        get_node_mt(mt->left,p,h-1);
    else
        get_node_mt(mt->right,p,h-1);
}
```

I reformatted the code a bit and removed a lot of braces. The compiler should've warned about this problem, IMHO.

Comment: Did you add the return statements?